# How to install terminology emulator on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: terminology

Is it possible to install **terminology** on Ubuntu 14.04?

I didn't find anything helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:enlightenment-git/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install terminology
```

This will install the latest Terminology (currently, version 0.6.99).

[image]

This is not the stable release though. If you want the stable release (currently, version 0.3, and I don't think it's supported on Ubuntu 14.04 yet), replace `ppa:enlightenment-git/ppa` in the above steps with `ppa:efl/trunk`.

Comment: Trying to install from the git ppa gives this error `dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libefl-bin_201507231116-29852~ubuntu14.10.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/embryo/include/default.inc', which is also in package libembryo-bin 1.8.6-2ubuntu1`. Trminology apparently installs, but `terminology: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libefl.so.1: undefined symbol: eo_hook_call_post`.

Comment: DANGER:  my terminal is v0.7 and was a default UBUNTU 16 LTS installation... https://www.debian.org/security/2016/dsa-3712

Comment: This does not work on Ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu 14.10, the correct [installation sequence](https://www.enlightenment.org/distros/ubuntu-start) is:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:niko2040/e19
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install enlightenment
sudo apt-get install terminology
```