# Problem installing Terminology terminal emulator

Tags: command-line

When trying to run/install Terminology on Ubuntu 14.04 I get the following error

```
symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libecore_evas.so.1: undefined symbol: _eina_log_state_shutdown
```

I guess the problem is with the elementary library, because when I tried to compile it from source as indicated on the [Enlightenmend site](https://www.enlightenment.org/download), I couldn't run the `make` command without obtaining this error.

I tried doing a `sudo make uninstall` on this library and then the Efl, Evas Generic Loaders, and Emotion Generic Players libraries (the ones needed for Terminology according to the Enlightenment web page). After that I added the `enlightenment-git/ppa` repository, and followed the steps of the [How to install terminology on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508725/how-to-install-terminology-emulator-on-ubuntu-14-04) post with the same result: when I run the `terminology` command, I still get the error, even though there are no visible errors during the installation.

I even tried the `niko2040/e19` repository but the same occurred, I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Why is you're library in /usr/local ? ppa package might've installed it there but it might also mean you haven't uninstalled your manually-compiled version properly. Try to check where ppa packages install stuff and if I'm correct and you have duplicate files in /usr and /usr/local, do some cleanup in the latter.

I had another idea before. It's just wrong, I haven't read the code in the question properly.

<s>Probably something's wrong with requirements. Try to locate a package that contains evas library, install it and find the appropriate so-file in /usr/{local/,}lib/ -if there's only older/newer version you can try either to symlink and hope or install/compile another version of the library.</s>

Anyway, you have to figure out why that library can't be loaded and fix whatever is the problem with it.

Comment: Your answer is very vague. Please explain in more detail, when to perform which steps exactly.

Comment: Mobile app messes with code listings. It's not only vague, but just incorrect.

Comment: @IvanAnishchuk Like what sort of clean up? if I have a duplicated file,  can I just delete the one un `usr/local/lib`

Comment: If there are manually-installed files (other libs and stuff from e11 you installed) in /usr/local I'd recommend identifying and removing them all. It can be rather complicated, especially if you have something else there, that's why it's not recommended to use `make install` at all unless you have some way of controlling installed files... (checkinstall is one way of doing that on ubuntu)

Comment: But you can start with one file, sure (assuming it is duplicated, of course).

Comment: Please [edit] your question/answer, if you want to add information. It's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.